# Prove the generalised tube lemma

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In Munkres' topology we are asked to prove the generalised tube lemma: Let $A,B$ be compact subspaces of $X,Y$ respectively. If $N$ is an open set in $X\times Y$ containing $A\times B$, then there exist open sets $U,V$ in $X,Y$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    A\times B\subset U\times V\subset N
\end{equation*}
My attempt is below:

We still need to prove the tube lemma in this context: If $N$ is an open set of $X\times Y$ containing $x_0\times B$, then $N$ contains some tube $W\times B$ about $x_0\times B$, where $W$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $X$. Since $x_0\times B$ is homeomorphic to $B$ and $B$ is compact, we say $x_0\times B$ can be finitely covered by basis elements of $X\times Y$ that lie in $N$:
\begin{equation*}
    U_1\times V_1,\dots,U_n\times V_n
\end{equation*}
Let $W=U_1\cap\dots\cap U_n$. We say $U_i\times V_i$'s also cover $W\times B$. Let $x\times y\in W\times B$ be arbitrary. Since $x_0\times y\in x_0\times B$ and $x_0\times B$ is finitely covered by $U_i\times V_i$'s, $y\in V_i$ for some $V_i$. Since $x\in W$, $x\in U_i$ for every $U_i$, so $x\times y\in U_i\times V_i$ for some $i$. We thus know $W\times B$ lies in $N$ also.

Similarly, we can also show that if $N$ is an open set of $X\times Y$ containing $A\times y_0$, then $N$ contains some tube $A\times M$ about $A\times y_0$, where $M$ is an open neighbourhood of $y_0$ in $Y$.

Now we go back to the problem. Since $N$ contains all of $A\times B$, every $x\times B$ and every $A\times y$ have tube $W_{x}\times B$ and $A\times M_{y}$. $W_x$'s and $M_y$'s form open coverings for $A$ and $B$, respectively. Since $A,B$ are compact, we know
\begin{align*}
    A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}W_{i}=U\\
    B\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}=V
\end{align*}
which just means
\begin{equation*}
    A\times B\subset U\times V\subset N
\end{equation*}

Is my proof ok?

Comment: it may be wiser to say by compactness, there exists a finite subset $F \subset X$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{j \in F}W_j$ and same for $B$ and the $M_i$. other than that it looks ok. Its just the finite sub cover may not have been in any particular order nor are they necessarily the same number of open sub covering.